# How do I create and then output a Date object using a String as the input? i.e. "13/04/1998"

Tags: java

This setup is not working. When I print out v1 I get an incorrect date in the wrong format as it includes the time as 00:00:0000.

Is there a way of overriding the Date objects methods for formatting (if there is any)?

```
public class Vehicle
{

    //**********Declarations**********
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;

    //********** Declaring Customer object **********
    private Customer customer = null;

    private String VIN;
    private Date dateOfManufacture;
    private Date dateOfSale = null;
    private Boolean sold = false;
    private char taxBand;
    private int costOfVehicle;


    //**********Constructor**********
    public Vehicle(String man, String mod, Customer custName, String VIN, String dateOfMan, char taxBand, int costOfVehicle)
    {
        this.manufacturer = man;
        this.model = mod;

        this.customer = custName;

        this.VIN = VIN;

        Date newDate = new Date(dateOfMan);
        this.dateOfManufacture = newDate;

        this.taxBand = taxBand;
        this.costOfVehicle = costOfVehicle;
    }

    public Date getDateOfManufacture()
    {
        return dateOfManufacture;
    }


    public void setDateOfManufacture(Date dateOfManufacture)
    {
        this.dateOfManufacture = dateOfManufacture;
    }


    public Date getDateOfSale()
    {
        return dateOfSale;
    }


    public void setDateOfSale(Date dateOfSale)
    {        
        this.dateOfSale = dateOfSale;
    }

    }


    //*******Driver class creating a new Vehicle object *******

    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Ford", "Fiesta", null, "123abc", "12/03/2000", 'c', 3000);
```

Comment: `DateFormat.parse()` is what you need

Comment: I guess this question can be asked with two or three lines of code. As it is now, it is hard to identify the interesting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the `Date` from `String` you can use `SimpleDateFormat` like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("13/04/1998");
```

Comment: Just want to add: This class is not threadsafe, so if you use multiple Threads, you'll need some kind of synchronization